# How to delimit a population based on the dates that accounts were opened on in teradata?

Tags: sql, sql-server, teradata

```
    CUST_ID     ACCT_ID         FICO_SCORE  DATE_APPLICATION_RECEIVED
1   48378281    2,200,263,271   577         5/3/2001
2   48378281    2,346,832,797   611         5/14/2003
3   48378281    2,210,263,271   560         5/2/2002
4   48378281    2,416,532,797   575         5/14/2005
```

Say that I have a list of customers with multiple accounts with my company in teradata, and I have their fico scores, and the date that their application for a new account with us are opened. A customer must have more than 2 accounts and may have up to 5 accounts. Above is how that table would look like for just one customer. How do I now delimit this population to just those customers that have accounts where their opening date was at least 6 months apart from each other for between their first opened account and second opened account? I just need count(unique(cust_id)) at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly you only care for the first two accounts being at least 6 months apart?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM
 (
   SELECT CUST_ID
   FROM tab
   QUALIFY  -- only the first account of a customer
      ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID
            ORDER BY DATE_APPLICATION_RECEIVED) = 1
   AND -- at least six months between this and the next row
      ADD_MONTHS(DATE_APPLICATION_RECEIVED, 6) 
       < MIN(DATE_APPLICATION_RECEIVED) 
         OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID
               ORDER BY DATE_APPLICATION_RECEIVED
               ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING)
 ) AS dt
```

Comment: +1 and thanks; always looking for good, simple examples of using ROWS BETWEEN.